# 32-Bit Application is failing on 32-bit OS but working on 64 bit machine

Tags: .net, memory, memory-leaks, 32bit-64bit, ram

We have 32 bit .net application which is calling some 3rd party dlls[c/C++].
On 32 bit OS with 2GB RAM, we continuously get "Attempted to read or write protected memory" error after calling dll.
But
On 64 bit OS with 4GB RAM, success rate is 50%
On 32 bit OS with 4GB RAM, success rate is 100%
Hence, it seems issue is due to memory is insufficient. , 
 But we observed that, while application is running on 2GB memory,and memory is available still we are getting "Attempted to Read or Write protected memory".
Can anyone suggest, what is going wrong even if memory is available ? 
Is it address space issue ? 
 We have tried LARGEADDRESSAWARE but getting same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, found out what is the problem.
My application has one thread which calls 3rd party c/c++ dlls.
If I remove this thread and execute the same code jn sequence then it works on 32 bit.
It seems 32 bit machine has different threading model as compare to 64 bit in .net.
Finally we managed to fix it, thanks everyone.